# TypeError: this is undefined in AsyncValidator

Tags: angular, typescript

this is my first question here, I hope there is no answer on that somewhere else. So...
I have an error in firefox

```
TypeError: this is undefined
    unique async-clientID.validator.ts:14
    Angular 20
        _executeAsyncValidators
        _executeAsyncValidators
        composeAsync
        _runAsyncValidator
        updateValueAndValidity
        setValue
        updateControl
        setUpViewChangePipeline
        _handleInput
        DefaultValueAccessor_input_HostBindingHandler
        executeListenerWithErrorHandling
        wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault
        decoratePreventDefault
        invokeTask
        onInvokeTask
        invokeTask
        runTask
        invokeTask
        invokeTask
        globalZoneAwareCallback
```

and in Chrome:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'service' of undefined
    at unique (async-clientID.validator.ts:14)
    at forms.js:1163
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at _executeAsyncValidators (forms.js:1163)
    at FormControl.asyncValidator (forms.js:1144)
    at FormControl._runAsyncValidator (forms.js:3030)
    at FormControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:3005)
    at FormControl.setValue (forms.js:3386)
    at updateControl (forms.js:2407)
    at DefaultValueAccessor.onChange (forms.js:2392)
```

My async-clientID.validator.ts looks like that and error is in line with `return this.service...`

```
@async-clientID.validator.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ClientsService } from '../services/clients.service';
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from "@angular/forms";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AsyncClientIDValidator {
    constructor(
        private service: ClientsService) {}

    unique(control: AbstractControl ): Observable<ValidationErrors | null>
14.        return this.service.getResourse(control);
    }
}
```

I use it in a ClientCreate component as `private validator: AsyncClientIDValidator`:

```
@client-create.component.ts file:
import { IClient } from './../clients/client';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AsyncClientIDValidator } from '../validators/async-clientID.validator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-client-create',
  templateUrl: './client-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client-create.component.css']
})
export class ClientCreateComponent {
  temp: IClient;
  clientCreateForm: FormGroup; 

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private validator: AsyncClientIDValidator
  ){ 
    this.temp = this.ICLientInitializeWithNulls();
    this.clientCreateForm = this.fb.group({
      customerID: [this.temp.customerID,
        Validators.required,
        this.validator.unique]
    });
  }
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: What is  this.ICLientInitializeWithNulls(); ..?

Comment: it a fn intializing 'temp' variable:  ICLientInitializeWithNulls() {
    return {
      customerID: null,
      companyName: null,
      contactName: null,
      contactTitle: null,
      address: null,
      city: null,
      region: null,
      postalCode: null,
      country: null,
      phone: null,
      fax: null
    }
  } Nothing special I think

Comment: `unique = (control: AbstractControl ): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => { ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is, that you provided the reference to the unbound `validator.unique` method.
You can go in two directions to solve it

1. use an arrow function to define the method:

```
export class AsyncClientIDValidator {
    constructor(
        private service: ClientsService) {}

    unique = (control: AbstractControl ): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => this.service.getResourse(control);
}
```

By using an arrow function the `unique` method will be created on the `AsyncClientIDValidator` with a fixed this context.

2. create a bound function instance of the `unique` method to pass it in the array:

```
export class ClientCreateComponent {
  temp: IClient;
  clientCreateForm: FormGroup; 

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private validator: AsyncClientIDValidator
  ){ 
    this.temp = this.ICLientInitializeWithNulls();
    this.clientCreateForm = this.fb.group({
      customerID: [this.temp.customerID,
        Validators.required,
        this.validator.unique.bind(this.validator) <----
]
    });
  }
```

With this solution you explicitly bind the `this` context for this function instance to the `his.validator` value of your `ClientCreateComponent`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any of 2 directions worked. Thanks!